# how can i get right result at the seperator of "|"?

Tags: regex, r

I want to split a string .

```
str <- "3 |6 | 9 | 12" 
unlist(strsplit(str,split="|")) 
[1] "3" " " "|" "6" " " "|" " " "9" " " "|" " " "1" "2"
```

How can I get the result "3 6 9 12"?

Comment: You could either use `split = "\\|"` or `fixed = T` inside `strsplit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a vector with all four substrings, you can use:

```
str <- "3 |6 | 9 | 12" 

strsplit(str, " *\\| *")[[1]]
# [1] "3"  "6"  "9"  "12"
```

Here, `" *"` means *any number of whitespaces*.

Note that `|` means *or* in regular expressions. You have to use double escapes for literal interpretation, i.e., `\\|`.

Answer (score 2):

I would actually forego `strsplit` and just use `scan` for something like this....

```
> str <- "3 |6 | 9 | 12" 
> str
[1] "3 |6 | 9 | 12"
> scan(text = str, sep = "|")
Read 4 items
[1]  3  6  9 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `gsub` to replace '|' by "empty". (with "fixed = TRUE" so "|" is a string to be matched as is, and not the "|" used in regexp)

```
str <- "3 |6 | 9 | 12" 
> gsub("|", "", str, fixed = TRUE)
[1] "3 6  9  12"
```